# Prime Number Theorem - Representing Integrals With Python

Tags: python, math, primes

I'm in a "COUNT PRIMES" challenge. **I need to count the number of primes to a specific limit that the user inputs.**

> Ex: count_primes(100000000000000) --Yes, i'm working with absolute
> huge numbers.. By using `limit/ln(limit)` I will get this
> aproximation:
>
> Output: ≅ 3102103442166
>
> This method is not 100% precise, but it's good for fast processing
> with this kind of numbers//my code took less than 1 sec to show this
> to me.

My code:

```
    import math
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    
    def count_primes(limit):
        return(f'N° Primes ≅ {round(limit / math.log(limit))}\n' #limit/ln(limit) 
               f'Prime density = {round((1/math.log(limit))*100, 2)}%') #1/ln(x)
    
    print(count_primes(100000000000000))
    print(f"--- exec in {time.time() - start_time} seconds ---")
```

```
N° Primes ≅ 3102103442166
Prime density = 3.1%
--- exec in 0.0 seconds ---
```

I need help to represent the Li(x) integral of the prime number theorem.

I can't post images yet, but it looks like this:

> Li(x) = ∫μ-->x dt/ln t

With higher limits, ex: (count_primes(100000)), this integral will be executed to fit the most precise approximation for the number of primes in the limit interval.

+By using this method, the final user can work with absolutely huge limits like 100,000,000,000,000 with a proper approximation and fast processing.

I have two questions:

1. Is this the correct method of doing what i'm thinking/trying to do? I mean, using this integral...
2. How can I represent this integral?

I've already tried Sieve of Eratosthenes, but I'm trying to work this way i've shown now.

I'd appreciate your explanation. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: Do you need an exact count?